# Moira, heal thyself

Tags: overwatch

What are Moira's options for healing herself? With no shields to regenerate, are my only option health packs, other team healers, and throwing a heal orb into a tight space? If so, how can I ensure that the orb stays relatively stationary (so as to maximize the self-heal)?

Comment: I haven't played Moira since PTR last week, but her healing orb seems to slow down when it's healing someone.  That includes yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moira has three options for self healing:

**Biotic Orb (Heal Ball)**

Biotic Orb will heal **75 hp/s** to a maximum of **300hp**. There are two ways that you can use this to heal yourself. Easiest way (as you noted in the question) is to find a small space such as a room or hallway with parallel surfaces. If you throw your ball perpendicular to these surfaces it will bounce back and forth until it times out or reaches max heal. Beyond just self healing, this is useful if you want to create a small "heal station" for teammates to heal up quickly.

The other slightly more difficult, but useful, way is to throw your ball in the direction that you wish to move and chasing it. When your ball is healing it will significantly slow it's movement speed allowing you to move along with it as you heal. This is great for fleeing a fight as you can heal while running away, but it makes your movement more predictable. Take care to aim this parallel to the ground, if you aim too low or high it will end up flying away into the sky. Also, be careful of any rouge bits sticking out from walls or floors that might cause your ball to bounce off in unintended directions.

**Biotic Grasp (Purple Right-click Beam)**

While your purple beam is attached to and damaging a target you will heal your self at a rate of **33 hp/s**. It has a surprising amount of range to it (around 20m) so don't be afraid to keep your distance and suck up some health from an enemy tank.

**Coalescence (Ultimate Beam)**

Moira's ultimate heals her at a rate of **50hp/s** regardless of if you are damaging anyone or not. So it can be used to save yourself as a last ditch effort. I wouldn't recommend it though, as her ultimate can be pretty good when used properly during a team fight.

[Source for Values](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Moira).

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the usual healing options (support teammates, health packs, spawn point), throwing a healing orb in your general direction of movement or calculating where it'd optimally bounce for you is one way of self-healing.

The other self-healing option that is unique to Moira is when she does damage with her primary fire, she also heals herself for a small amount.